# How should I use Git for development and production servers?

Tags: git, ftp

I've just been brought into a project where the developers have been working directly on the production site over ftp - then pushing changes to the master repo on git afterwards. I want to bring in a development server, but as I'm a newbie to Git I'm not 100% how it integrates into the workflow. My current understanding is that it would go as follows:

1. Developers code via ftp on to the development server
2. Progress is then pushed to a development branch on the Git Repo
3. Releases can then be merged to the master branch
4. The production site is updated by pulling code from the master repo.

Does that sound about right?

Comment: _"1. Developers code via `ftp` on to the development server"_ - Well Git is peer-to-peer and there is no central server so developers should be coding via a `local` Git repo then `pushing` that to your "central" or _origin_ repo (step 2). Your Production server can then pull from `origin`.  I quite like [Atlassians GitFlow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)

Comment: @MickyDuncan Atlassians GitFlow is nice, and enforces accepted workflow conventions.  The tool itself however I have found to be somewhat buggy and doesn't well handle small groups of developers who need to be able to task switch more often (as bad as that is)

Comment: Thanks Micky - my description was poor. The developers are developing locally then pushing to GitHub.

Comment: @lassombra I was describing the `process` and **not** the `tool` _SourceTree_ . SourceTree is merely the GUI that uses Git behind the scenes.  Don't like the tool? Then do GitFlow from the *command-line**

Comment: @MickyDuncan Sorry for any confusion, I was specifically referring to the gitflow extension which implements automatic branch naming, merge, and branch deletion based on workflow activities.  That is the part I have found buggy both on the command line and in SourceTree.  The principles it enforces however are spot on.

Comment: @lassombra No worries. Sorry to hear that. I've found it better than TortoiseSVN at least ;)

Comment: @MickyDuncan That's like saying C++ is better than Basic  Just saying, it's kinda obvious that one tool is a swiss army knife and the other one is just a folding screwdriver.

Comment: @lassombra I'm saying that in my experience Git has been more reliable **branching; merging;** and **branch deletion** wise via SourceTree or via the command-line than SVN is with just merging.  its not "obvious" until one has tried both tools perhaps

Comment: @MickyDuncan True, I have used CVS, SVN, and GIT and would prefer GIT 100% of the time now.  The command line functions of git itself are great and I've never had problems.  Same with Source Tree.  The only thing I've ever run into problems with is gitflow which is an extension, not a native part of git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convention is to have a Development branch which represents a deployable state for the code along with feature and fix branches that will eventually be merged into that branch.  Finally you conventionally have branches representing each server.

Developers should never code direct to the server they should code to git and the process of getting to the server should be a deploy from git.  There are CI tools for almost any environment that will make that process automatic by monitoring git repositories so don't be afraid to use them.

Ultimately, GIT should be the focus of the developers and they really shouldn't even know the server's IP addresses (they don't need to) Systems admins should be setting up CI (Continuous Integration) tools that run unit tests and deploy automatically if everything is kosher.

Comment: Thats a solid answer lassombra.